# What is a "code object" mentioned in this TypeError message?

Tags: python, cpython

While trying to use Python's `exec` statement, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: exec: arg 1 must be a string, file, or code object
```

I don't want to pass in a string or a file, but what is a code object, and how do I create one?

Comment: Why are you using exec? And what's wrong with passing in a string or file?

Comment: They're described in the [Code Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/code.html) section of the [Python/C API Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One way to create a code object is to use `compile` built-in function:

```
>>> compile('sum([1, 2, 3])', '', 'single')
<code object <module> at 0x19ad730, file "", line 1>
>>> exec compile('sum([1, 2, 3])', '', 'single')
6
>>> compile('print "Hello world"', '', 'exec')
<code object <module> at 0x19add30, file "", line 1>
>>> exec compile('print "Hello world"', '', 'exec')
Hello world
```

also, functions have the function attribute `__code__` (also known as `func_code` in older versions) from which you can obtain the function's code object:

```
>>> def f(s): print s
... 
>>> f.__code__
<code object f at 0x19aa1b0, file "<stdin>", line 1>
```

Comment: The bit that puzzles me about the OP's question (and acceptance of this answer) is that if they're going to pass a string to `compile`, most of the time they may as well pass it directly to `exec` and let `exec` compile it to a code object behind the scenes. The only reason to call `compile` directly is if the application has a specific need to separate the compilation and execution steps (e.g. the same code object may be invoked more than once, or the syntax check is desired when the code is entered, even if it won't be run until later).

Comment: What does the line number indicate in the output of compile command?

Comment: @YatShan: It's not the output of the compile command. It's the string return from the automatic call to `repr(f.__code__)` the Python interactive shell made to so the value of the last expression typed-in (i.e. `f.__code__`). It says "line 1" because that's the line number of the function `def`.

Answer (score 30):

There is an excellent blog post by Dan Crosta explaining this topic, including how to create code objects manually, and how to disassemble them again:

> [Exploring Python Code Objects](http://late.am/post/2012/03/26/exploring-python-code-objects)

Comment: Good link. For posterity, if the link becomes dead: the page discusses creating code objects via `compile`, understanding the object's internals, and looks at the underlying byte code a bit.

Answer (score 18):

Code objects are described [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#index-59):

> Code objects represent *byte-compiled*
>   executable Python code, or *bytecode*.
>   The difference between a code object
>   and a function object is that the
>   function object contains an explicit
>   reference to the function’s globals
>   (the module in which it was defined),
>   while a code object contains no
>   context; also the default argument
>   values are stored in the function
>   object, not in the code object
>   (because they represent values
>   calculated at run-time). Unlike
>   function objects, code objects are
>   immutable and contain no references
>   (directly or indirectly) to mutable
>   objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Disassemble code with `dis.dis` to see what it contains**

A pretty fundamental thing you can do to inspect a `code` object is to disassemble it as [mentioned on the link from Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13469876/895245):

```
import ast
import dis

myast = ast.parse('''def inc(i):
    return i + 1

print(inc(2))
''')
# print(ast.dump(myast, indent=2))
print(ast.unparse(myast))
code = compile(myast, 'mymodule', 'exec')
exec(code)
dis.dis(code)
```

Output:

```
def inc(i):
    return i + 1
print(inc(2))
3
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object inc at 0x7f85fbfae800, file "mymodule", line 1>)
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (inc)

  4           8 PUSH_NULL
             10 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
             12 PUSH_NULL
             14 LOAD_NAME                0 (inc)
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             18 PRECALL                  1
             22 CALL                     1
             32 PRECALL                  1
             36 CALL                     1
             46 POP_TOP
             48 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             50 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object inc at 0x7f85fbfae800, file "mymodule", line 1>:
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BINARY_OP                0 (+)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

So we can see that this actually explains what code actually contains, which is Python bytecode, and which is documented on the `dis` module itself: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/dis.html

Tested on Python 3.11.4, Ubuntu 23.04.