# Python built-in function "compile". What is it used for?

Tags: python, built-in

I came across a built-in function [`compile`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#compile) today. Though i read the documentation but still do not understand it's usage or where it is applicable. Please can anyone explain with example the use of this function. I will really appreciate examples.

From the documentation, the function takes some parameters as shown below.

```
compile(source, filename, mode[, flags[, dont_inherit]])
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It is not that commonly used.  It is used when you have Python source code in string form, and you want to make it into a Python code object that you can keep and use.  Here's a trivial example:

```
>>> codeobj = compile('x = 2\nprint "X is", x', 'fakemodule', 'exec')
>>> exec(codeobj)
X is 2
```

Basically, the code object converts a string into an object that you can later call `exec` on to run the source code in the string.  (This is for "exec" mode; the "eval" mode allows use of `eval` instead, if the string contains code for a single expression.) This is not a common task, which is why you may never run across a need for it.

The main use for it is in metaprogramming or embedding situations.  For instance, if you have a Python program that allows users to script its behavior with custom Python code, you might use `compile` and `exec` to store and execute these user-defined scripts.

Another reason `compile` is rarely used is that, like `exec`, `eval`, and their ilk, `compile` is a potential security hole.  If you take user code in string form and compile it and later exec it, you could be running unsafe code.  (For instance, imagine that in my example above the code was `formatYourHardDrive()` instead of `print x`.)

Comment: what if I have strings of two files: `py1.py` and `py2.py` (consider I get those strings from database cells, uploaded by user by selecting those files in browser interface), wherein `py1.py` calls function written in `py2.py`. Is there any way I can handle this?

Comment: @Mahesha999: There might be a way, but not a simple way.  That's definitely out of scope for a comment here.  You could try asking it as a separate question.

Answer (score 21):

`compile` is a lower level version of `exec` and `eval`. It does not execute or evaluate your statements or expressions, but returns a code object that can do it. The modes are as follows:

1. `compile(string, '', 'eval')` returns the code object that would have been executed had you done `eval(string)`. Note that you *cannot* use statements in this mode; only a (single) expression is valid. Used for a single expression.
2. `compile(string, '', 'exec')` returns the code object that would have been executed had you done `exec(string)`. You can use any number of statements here. Used for an entire module.
3. `compile(string, '', 'single')` is like the `exec` mode, but it will ignore everything except for the first statement. Note that an `if`/`else` statement with its results is considered a single statement. Used for one single statement.

Take a look that the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#compile). There is also an awesome (well, dumbed down) explanation at http://joequery.me/code/python-builtin-functions/#compile with an excellent example of usage.

Comment: I preferred it when you called my explanation awesome ;)

Comment: @JoeQuery Wow, hello! I have learnt loads from your stuff since I started! Thank you!

Comment: see also the accepted answer from @max-shawabkeh here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python

Comment: dumbed down explanations __are__ awesome

Answer (score 6):

What specifically don't you understand? The documentation explains that it will:

> Compile the source into a code or AST object. Code objects can be executed by an [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) statement or evaluated by a call to [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#eval). source can either be a Unicode string, a Latin-1 encoded string or an AST object. Refer to the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ast.html#module-ast) module documentation for information on how to work with AST objects.

So it takes python code, and returns on of those two things

- `exec` will execute the python code
- `eval` will evaluate an expression, which is less functional than `exec`
- `ast` allows you to navigate the [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) that the code generates

Comment: +1 for bringing up ASTs - what compile is actually used for [1].
[1] - http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Demo/parser/unparse.py?view=markup

Answer (score 1):

**`compile` an `ast` tree**

Another cool thing you can do with `compile` is to compile an `ast` tree, rather than just code strings. This might be of interest for AI code generation, where generating the ast tree may be more interesting than generating strings, since ultimately understanding the program means understanding the AST tree in the first place.

Here's an example:

```
import ast
from ast import *

myast = ast.parse('''def inc(i):
    return i + 1

print(inc(2))
''')
# print(ast.dump(myast, indent=2))
print(ast.unparse(myast))
code = compile(myast, 'mymodule', 'exec')
exec(code)
print()

myast2 = ast.fix_missing_locations(Module(
  body=[
    FunctionDef(
      name='inc',
      args=arguments(
        posonlyargs=[],
        args=[
          arg(arg='i')],
        kwonlyargs=[],
        kw_defaults=[],
        defaults=[]),
      body=[
        Return(
          value=BinOp(
            left=Name(id='i', ctx=Load()),
            op=Add(),
            right=Constant(value=1)))],
      decorator_list=[]),
    Expr(
      value=Call(
        func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()),
        args=[
          Call(
            func=Name(id='inc', ctx=Load()),
            args=[
              Constant(value=2)],
            keywords=[])],
        keywords=[]))],
  type_ignores=[]))
# print(ast.dump(myast2, indent=2))
print(ast.unparse(myast))
code2 = compile(myast2, 'mymodule', 'exec')
exec(code2)
```

Output:

```
def inc(i):
    return i + 1
print(inc(2))
3

def inc(i):
    return i + 1
print(inc(2))
3
```

So we see that using `ast.*` objects we were able to construct Python code entirely as the ast tree in a way that matched Python code that comes from a regular Python code string.

**Inspecting the `code` object**

To understand what `code` contains and how to inspect it, see also: [What is a "code object" mentioned in this TypeError message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768684/what-is-a-code-object-mentioned-in-this-typeerror-message)

Tested on Python 3.11.4, Ubuntu 23.04.