# When to use "eval" mode rather than "exec" with Python compile()

Tags: python, built-in

Python's built-in `compile` function has `eval`, `exec` and `single` modes. `single` mode seems a bit useless ([ref](https://joequery.me/code/python-builtin-functions/#compile)). How about the `eval` and `exec`?

- eval: works on an `expression`
- exec: works on `statements`

But an `expression` *is* a `statement`. My question is: why not just use `exec` all the time?

PS: I've read some related questions like [Python built-in function "compile". What is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443939/python-built-in-function-compile-what-is-it-used-for). They do a good job explaining the difference between the modes, but doesn't directly answer my question.

Comment: ``single`` is what drives the REPL, so any source that implies it's useless or "cannot think of a good use" for it should be approached with care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like the `eval` builtin, the `compile` eval mode creates a code object that evaluates an expression *and returns its result*. In contrast, exec mode does not return a result.

```py
>>> exec_code = compile("1 + 2", "<stack overflow>", "exec")
>>> eval(exec_code)  # no result for "exec" mode code
>>> eval_code = compile("1 + 2", "<stack overflow>", "eval")
>>> eval(eval_code)  # some result for "eval" mode code
3
```

---

> But an expression is a statement.

This is not true. An expression evaluates to a value, a statement does not.

While [expression statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements) mean an expression can be used "as a" statement, that does not make the two equivalent. An expression statement *contains* an expression; when run, the statement evaluates the expression but discards the result.

Comment: I see. I have a block of code that I need to `eval` and get its result. The code is too complex to be fit into one expression. Is it even possible?

Comment: @F.S. Since a block of code cannot have a result, it's by definition not possible. The closest thing is to ``exec`` the code with an explicit global namespace, and fetch all data of interest from that namespace – but it requires the code to actually write that data to the namespace.

Answer (score 4):

An expression is not a statement, but there is a kind of statement (the expression statement) that consists of a single expression. This nifty bit of indirection allows the parser to think a Python module as a sequence of statements, rather than a sequence of statements and/or expressions.

An expression has a value; an expression statement does not: it simply evaluates the expression (primarily for its side effects) and discards the value.

`eval` returns the value of the evaluated expression.

`exec` will execute an expression as an expression statement, but discard the value of the expression. (`exec` itself is a function which is primarily called in expression statements, rather than as part of a larger expression.)

Answer (score 0):

updated and extra examples.

The accepted answer's examples do not working in python 3.10 any more.

```
>> exec_code = eval(compile("1 + 2", "<stack overflow>", "exec"))
>>> eval(exec_code)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

Updated examples for python 3.10

```
>> exec_code = compile("1 + 2", "<stack overflow>", "exec")
>>> exec(exec_code)
>>> eval_code = compile("1 + 2", "<stack overflow>", "eval")
>>> eval(eval_code)  # some result for "eval" mode code
3
```

Example of a block of code

```
>>> a='''
... b=1+4
... print(b)
... '''
>>> exec_code = compile(a, "<stack overflow>", "exec")
>>> exec(exec_code)
5
```