# Python 3.6.5 "is" and "==" for integers beyond caching interval

Tags: python, object, reference, compare

I want to preface this by saying that I know the difference between `==` and `is` one is for references and the other is for objects. I also know that python caches the integers in the range `(-5, 256)` at startup so they should work when comparing them with `is`.

However I have seen a strange behaviour.

```
>>> 2**7 is 2**7
True
>>> 2**10 is 2**10
False
```

This is to be expected, `2**7` is `128` and `2**10` is `1024`, one is in the interval `(-5, 256)` and the other is not.

However...

```
>>> 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000
True
```

Why does this return `True`? It is obviously a value WAY above any kind of caching interval and `2**10 is 2**10` clearly showed that `is` does actually not work on integers above `256`. So... why does this happen?

Comment: After answering, I realize that this point **is** covered in an answer to ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) (though it might not stand out).

Comment: Actually, due to peephole-optimization `2**10 is 2**10` is `True` with Python3.8 (and probably Python3.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPython detects constant values in your code and re-uses them to save memory. These constants are stored on [code objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768684/what-is-a-python-code-object), and can even be accessed from within python:

```
>>> codeobj = compile('999 is 999', '<stdin>', 'exec')
>>> codeobj
<code object <module> at 0x7fec489ef420, file "<stdin>", line 1>
>>> codeobj.co_consts
(999, None)
```

Both operands of your `is` refer to this very same 999 integer. We can confirm this by [dissassembling the code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis):

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(codeobj)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (999)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (999)
              4 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the first two `LOAD_CONST` instructions both load the constant with index `0`, which is the 999 number.

**However**, this only happens if the two numbers are compiled at the same time. If you create each number in a separate code object, they will no longer be identical:

```
>>> x = 999
>>> x is 999
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Python *is* compiled.  The expression was compiled all at once and its literals are shared when possible.  Any **operation**, like your exponentiation, or adding and subtracting 1 from one side, will break the identity. (Python could in theory do constant folding and thereby extend the set of `is`-identical expressions, but it doesn’t bother.)

Performing **multiple compilations** will also break this:

```
>>> x=300
>>> x is 300
False
```