# Python ID Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

When i am entering num1 = any number till 256 and num2 = same number as num1 getting same id for both objects but when i am using num1 = 257 and num2 = 257 its providing different ID to both objects. why? let me know about this issue?

```
>>> num1 = 256
>>> num2 = 256
>>> print(id(num1), id(num2))
140703620028824 140703620028824
>>> num1 = 257
>>> num2 = 257
>>> print(id(num1), id(num2))
2102222951568 2102222952080
```

Python Version: 3.12.1

Comment: Can't reproduce... I get the same I'd for both https://ideone.com/yTKnf3

Comment: @journpy it will behave differently when executing a script (where the compiler can analyse the whole thing and do constant folding) compared to executing line by line in the REPL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347581/why-does-the-is-operator-behave-differently-in-a-script-vs-the-repl

Comment: @slothrop ok will have a look

Comment: @slothrop it appears from the answers that this seems to happen for CPython implemented interpreters. It may not be for other implementations.

Comment: Quite so, but even within CPython you'll get different behaviour from a script than from the REPL, because of constant-folding at the compile step.

Comment: @slothrop Clearer now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in python small integers (=<256) are pre allocated, when you define a variable with a small integer, it is not creating a new ID, but rather giving it the one that already exists. This means that if you have 2 different variables that are 2 and 2, or 50 and 50, or 250 and 250, the ID will be the same. However, python does make a new ID for integers above 256, which means 2 different variables with the value of 257 will have a different ID.

edit: it does seem to depend on which interpreter you are using, as many will reuse the same ID anyway, but this is not an integral part of python but rather just the interpreter. It also has to do with how the interpreter deals with memory allocation.